# UsbDeviceConnection ControlTransfer() returns -1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, usbserial

I've been writing an application to communicate with a CP2102 usb to serial chip in xamarin android. I can succssesfully grant premission to open the device and claim the interfaces. After I open the device I use these lines of code to claim the interface and get the endpoints:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mDevice.InterfaceCount; i++)
                {
                    UsbInterface usbIface = mDevice.GetInterface(i);
                    if (mConnection.ClaimInterface(usbIface, true))
                    {
                        Log.Debug(TAG, "claimInterface " + i + " SUCCESS");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.Debug(TAG, "claimInterface " + i + " FAIL");
                    }
                }

                UsbInterface dataIface = mDevice.GetInterface(mDevice
                        .InterfaceCount - 1);
                for (int i = 0; i < dataIface.EndpointCount; i++)
                {
                    UsbEndpoint ep = dataIface.GetEndpoint(i);
                    if (ep.Type == UsbAddressing.XferBulk)
                    {
                        if (ep.Direction == UsbAddressing.In)
                        {
                            mReadEndpoint = ep;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mWriteEndpoint = ep;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Then I try to use the ControlTransfer to communicate with the device but it always returns -1. This is the code I've written to set the config:

```
 int r = mConnection.ControlTransfer(UsbAddressing.Out, 0x00, 0x0001, 0, null, 0, 5000);
```

The r is always -1 and indicates that there is an error in communication, though The device works perfect when I run this command in java android:

```
mConnection.controlTransfer(0x41, 0x00, 0x0001, 0, null, 0, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was the UsbAddressing.Out. It is 0. It should be 0x41 for this type of request according to the documentation of the chip set. To tell the trust I shouldn't have asked this question at all. It seems that Using this type of chip in Xamarin is not possible since it doesn't allow you to send custom request types. You have to write the code in java and import it using JNI. It's the only applicable solution, as far as I know. I think this is one of the main reasons that in [xamarinusbserial project](https://bitbucket.org/lusovu/xamarinusbserial) they have used JNI too.

I hope somebody in xamarin read this post. It's too annoying to face such troubles when you're working with a commercial app, this expensive!!